# convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z}{n!})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

I want to show that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z}{n!})$ is convergent (or uniformly convergent) (z is complex)

Can I use the Theorem:

The infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

Comment: That's exactly what you need

Comment: @user134824 But I think, $a_n$ is real in theorem but I have complex series.. I confused..

Comment: The theorem you are looking at may only be stated for real numbers, but it is true for complex numbers as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\left|\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left( 1-\frac{z}{n!}\right)\right|
=
&
\lim_{N\to\infty}\exp\left(\log\left(\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left| 1-\frac{z}{n!}\right|\right)\right)
\\
=
&
\lim_{N\to\infty}\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\left| 1-\frac{z}{n!}\right|\right)
\\
\leq
&
\lim_{N\to\infty}\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\left[1+\frac{|z|}{n!}\right]\right)
\\
\end{align}
Due to inequality $\log (x)<x-1$ for all $x>0$,
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\left|\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left( 1-\frac{z}{n!}\right)\right|
\leq
&
\lim_{N\to\infty}\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\frac{|z|}{n!}\right]\right)
\\
=
&
\lim_{N\to\infty}\exp\left(|z|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\frac{1}{n!}\right]\right)
\\=
&
\exp\left(|z|\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\frac{1}{n!}\right]\right)
\\
=
&
\exp\left(|z|e\right)
\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But I want to ask one more question... What is order of this entire function (I mean this infinite product).. I dont know what is order, do you know?

Comment: @corciacandy What do you mean by 'order'? If you are talking about convergence order towards the convergence of the product is uniform or punctually you can use the M test Weiersstrass to achieve uniform convergence.

Comment: This quuestion from my homework.. But I dont understand what is order.. 
by the way I used M test to show uniformly convergency. Thank you :)